# Почему код работает правильно только со стрелочной функцией?

Tags: javascript

Задача проверить все ли элементы из массива keyRecipe присутствуют в массиве availableKeys . Если хотя бы одного нет, возвращать 0.

Так работает

```
if (!keyRecipe.every(element => availableKeys.includes(element))) return 0;
```

Так нет

```
if (!keyRecipe.every(function(element){availableKeys.includes(element)})) return 0;
```

Не могу понять почему со стрелочной функцией код работает, а при использовании обычной сразу срабатывает return 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!keyRecipe.every(function(element){return availableKeys.includes(element)})) return 0;
                                       ^^^^^^
```